# Angular Material: mat-error shows only when from-control was touched

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have two reactive forms inside my angular app.
I want to show the `<mat-error>` message conditionally.
Inside my first form i manage to do it with no problems, but in the second it shows only when the form control was touched.

**First form work as it should**

```
<div class="form-container__form__field">
  <mat-form-field class="form-input">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="on"
           formControlName="placeType"
           matInput
           placeholder="*סוג המקום">
    <mat-error *ngIf="formSubmitted &&
               newPlannerForm.controls['placeType'].errors">
      חובה למלא את סוג המקום!</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

**Second shows only when the control is touched**

```
<mat-form-field 
class="inner-container__form__inputs__personal-info__input__field">
              <input 
              matInput 
              placeholder="*שם" maxlength="40" type="text" 
              formControlName="name" autocomplete="off">
              <mat-error 
                *ngIf="workingTimeSubmitted && 
                teamCreationForm.get('name').hasError('required')">
                יש למלא את שם איש הצוות!
              </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: All the documentation is here : https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown

Comment: @PierreMallet I already read it. I want to know the reason why the behavior was changed in the second Form

Comment: It seems that the newPlannerForm is submitted automatically in your application because the default behavior or mat-error is to display error after user interaction on the formControl or when the parent form is submitted. So the second case you expose seems to be the normal behavior.

Comment: @PierreMallet Thanks for the help. I didn't add a submit button.

Comment: Are you using a custom ErrorStateMatcher ?

Comment: if possible please create a demo over stackblitz.

Comment: If you read the documentation linked, it clearly says ;) `By default, these error messages are shown when the control is invalid and either the user has interacted with (touched) the element or the parent form has been submitted`

Answer (score 1):

It is a designed behavior according to [the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown). But it is possible to override it by implementing a custom `ErrorStateMatcher`.

Here is how you can **achieve this**:

1. Create a custom `ErrorStateMatcher`

   ```
   export class InstantErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
     isErrorState(control: FormControl | null,
                  form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
       return control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched);
     }
   }
   ```
2. Declare a filed of the newly created type in your component code

   ```
   errorStateMatcher = new InstantErrorStateMatcher();
   ```
3. Refer to the custom error state matcher in your template

   ```
   <input matInput formControlName="yourFormControl"
       [errorStateMatcher]="errorStateMatcher">
   ```

You can find the complete example in [this repository](https://github.com/Shpota/go-angular). Look at [this component](https://github.com/Shpota/go-angular/blob/master/webapp/src/app/student-dialog/student-dialog.component.ts).

Comment: If you don't want to set this on every form control you can provide the custom error state matcher at the component level  
`providers: [
  { provide: ErrorStateMatcher, useClass: InstantErrorStateMatcher }
]`